# how to enable JavaScript in my PDF reader,where my pdf reader is not adobe acrobat reader

Tags: javascript, pdf

My PDF reader does not support any JavaScript embedded PDF file, and these PDFs are supported by another PDF reader like adobe PDF reader, Foxit PDF reader.

how can I get the support of JavaScript like adobe or other JavaScript supported PDF reader?

I got an idea that core JavaScript language is useful to do this, but how to adapt this into my PDF reader I still don't know.

Comment: You are correct that you'll need the JS core. After that, you'll need to reproduce the Acrobat JavaScript Object and Event Model which, frankly, is not trivial. That's why so few PDF viewers support JavaScript in PDF. Foxit and Readdle don't even support the full suite of JS Objects that Acrobat does.

Comment: Thanks you.Is there any third party js library which provide adobe like JavaScript object and event.It would be helpful.

Comment: No. That would be too easy :)